# How many real values of x satisfy the equation?

Tags: quadratics, mathematica, quadratic-variation

How many real values of x satisfy the following
equation:
$$|x|+|x+1|=1$$

And when we change the sign:
$$|x|+|x-1|=1$$
how does the answer differ?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it is in english

Comment: Just break these up into cases according to whether $x$ and $x\pm 1$ are positive or negative.

Comment: @lulu i break the eqation in a cases but after that I'm lill confused i want a best way or a method to tackle this type of question ..plzz tell me how i proceed step by step

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/koejl2h3ny

Comment: Please make an effort.  This really is the best way to proceed, there are so few cases.  Just try it.

Comment: @lulu i know this method to solve this problem but whenver modulus function  came i just became confused

Comment: It is notable that x solves the first equation if and only if -x solves the second equation, so you really only need to solve the first one.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen yupp got it

Answer (score 6):

I would start with the case $x\geq 0$ then we have $$x+x+1=1$$
For $$-1\le x<0$$ we get $$-x+x+1=1$$
and for $x<-1$ we obtain $-x-x-1=1$
and for the second equation i would start with
$$x\geq 1$$ so $x+x-1=1$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with absolute values is to note that $|x|$ behaves like $x$ when $x \geq 0$ and $-x$ when $x \leq 0$. Similarly $|x +1|$ behaves like $x + 1$ for $x \geq -1$ and $-x-1$ for $x \leq -1$. This gives you some cases to check for your first equation. For example, a first case:
$$
-x -x -1 = 1 \text{ when } x \leq -1 \implies -2x = 2 \implies x = -1
$$
The rest I'm sure you can figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Sonnhard's answer already covers the cases, but you can also try the following, based on the fact that *when we know* that both sides of an equation are non-negative, then rising them to the second power doesn't "add trash" to the set of solutions:

$$|x|+|x+1|=1\implies x^2+2|x(x+1)|+(x+1)^2=1^2=1\implies$$

$$2x^2+2x+2|x(x+1)|=0\stackrel{\div 2}\implies x(x+1)+|x(x+1)|=0$$

The last one above is an equation of the form $\;a+|a|=0\;$, which can be true only when $\;a\le 0\;$ , and from here that our equation's solution is

$$x(x+1)\le0\iff -1\le x\le0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function with an absolute minimum then the solutions of 
$$ f(x)=1 $$
are $0,1$ or $2$ according to $1<\min f, 1=\min f, 1>\min f$.
If a function of such kind also fulfills $f(x)=f(K-x)$, then $\min f=f\left(\frac{K}{2}\right)$.